# sort array with integer strings type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array of integers of type string.

```
var a = ['200','1','40','0','3'];
```

## output

```
>>> var a = ['200','1','40','0','3'];
console.log(a.sort());
["0", "1", "200", "3", "40"]
```

---

I'll also have a mixed type array. e.g.

```
var c = ['200','1','40','apple','orange'];
```

## output

```
>>> var c = ['200','1','40','apple','orange']; console.log(c.sort());
["1", "200", "40", "apple", "orange"]
```

==================================================
The integers of string type gets unsorted.

Comment: How do you need to sort it? Numbers first in numeric order, then alphas in alphabetical?

Comment: So, what do you need?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, numbers first then alphabetically....

Comment: @user1051068 Please update the question with expected output.

Comment: @user1051068 Try `['200','1','40','orange','apple']` and you will see that strings are sorted, too. Your example has already sorted strings. And `"1", "200", "40"` is a correct order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others said, you can write your own comparison function:

```
var arr = ["200", "1", "40", "cat", "apple"]
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});

// ["1", "40", "200", "apple", "cat"]
```

Comment: He added that after I finished :) Just updated mine, but I like your one liner

Comment: funny thing is that `parseInt()` is unnecesary (although it makes things clearer) :)

Comment: c = ['200','1','10','40','cba','abc'];

Run the function

["200", "1", "10", "40", "cba", "abc"]

No Luck

Answer (score 6):

This should be what you're looking for

```
var c = ['200','1','40','cba','abc'];
c.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    else return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});
// ["1", "40", "200", "abc", "cba"]
```

Comment: If alphas don't need sorting

Comment: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) does not accept a radix argument. More importantly, note that just using the `-` operator will cast the strings to numbers (and faster, too). In other words, just `return a-b`.

Comment: FAILS to sort if there is another integer of string type at last

var data = ['88','331','11','46','4445', '200', 'a', '300'];
alert(data.sort(function(a, b) {
                                return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b); 
                                })
    );

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own sort function.

```
a.sort(function(a,b)) {
    var intValA = parseInt(a, 10);
    var intValB = parseInt(b, 10);

    if (!isNaN(parseInt(a, 10))) && !isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)) {
        // we have two integers
        if (intValA > intValB)
            return 1;
        else if (intValA < intValB)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) && isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)))
        return 1;
    if (isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) && !isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)))
        return -1;

    // a and b are not integers
    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Isn't IsNan applied after parseInt will always return false?

Comment: You can make this much less verbose with ternary operators instead of so many if statements, e.g. `return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0`

Comment: @Phrogz, yes, I was trying to make the return details easier to read, but you are right - it's longer than it needs to be.

Comment: also, if both are numbers you can just return the difference. If only one of them is a number then you can compare them as strings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, though I dont know jQuery much, but from you guys examples, I summarized the code as follows which works as per my requirement

## to be used in firebug

```
var data = ['10','2', 'apple', 'c' ,'1', '200', 'a'], temp;
temp = data.sort(function(a,b) {
         var an = +a;
         var bn = +b;
          
         if (!isNaN(an) && !isNaN(bn)) {
             return an - bn;
         } 
         return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0;
     }) ;
alert(temp);
```

Comment: just so you now `+a` coerces a to integer if it can, otherwise returns `NaN`. employing coersion Kazuki's answer can be the shortest one:`arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});`

Comment: @soulcheck `+a` coerces to a Number, not an "integer".

Comment: @Kazuki, soulcheck did some modification which meets my criteria..
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Most javascript implementations, as far as I know, provide a function you can pass in to provide your own custom sorting.

[Mozilla sort Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)